# How to get URL's of web service methods from the URL of web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi

I have web service URL `http://mycompany.com:8081/isapi/MyService.dll` with WSDL URL `http://mycompany.com:8081/isapi/MyService.dll/wsdl/IMyService` and I have the following operation defined in WSDL:

```
<operation name="test">
    <input message="tns:test4Request"/>
    <output message="tns:test4Response"/>
</operation>
```

I would like to execute/call this test procedure from the Postman or other similar tool (maybe even browser can be good for this GET request) - but I don't know what URL to call. What is the convention how to get URLs of web service procedures from the URL of the web service itself?

I have created web service in Delphi and I would like to consume it from C# but I receive error message:

```
client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'
```

I tried:

```
http://mycompany.com:8081/isapi/MyService.dll/test?Value=OK
```

but the response contained no body, it contained headers only:

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →application/x-msdownload
Date →Mon, 14 Nov 2016 09:24:47 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=99
Server →Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23
```

Comment: OK, I understood. The http://mycompany.com:8081/isapi/MyService.dll/soap/IMyService is the URL for methods and the method name and parameters should be provided in the SOAP XML in the request's body.

Comment: isapi? Apache? 'x-msdownload'? are you sure you've got [mod_isapi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_isapi.html) installed?